# Am I able to retrieve document from time machine after a clean install and setup new account with same username?

Tags: time-machine

I used time machine previously and I have done a clean install to get back some space on my mac. At setup process I skipped to use time machine I just wanted to get my machine up and running and set up a new account with same username as earlier. Am I able to retrieve document from backup time machine used to done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drill down into the Time Machine folder hierarchy just like any other disk...

[Time Machine Drive] > Backups.backupd > [Computer name] > Latest - then you're into the old hierarchy as it was on your previous system.

if Latest has been overwritten by the new system then you'd have to dig by date or use search.